# Link file from another language wikipedia

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia

I am using [[File:example.jpg]] in my infobox, but it does not show, since I am writing for Serbian Wikipedia, and file is uploaded to Wikipedia in English. Is there a way to link to this file from other language Wikipedia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on. If you host your wiki and have access to the configuration of it, you could use [`$wgForeignFileRepos`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgForeignFileRepos) to point to the wiki where the file(s) is/are hosted. This basically allows anyone on your wiki to use images from the configured foreign wiki as if they were hosted on the same wiki.

However, if you're only the user of the wiki, you can not do that. MediaWiki does not allow to embed files from other wikis without the configuration change mentioned above.